# Declare module in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

What is the different when I declare

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
 'uiCropper'
]);
```

and

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
 uiCropper
]);
```

The first way work for me.
I use ES6 import module (import uiCropper from 'ui-cropper';)

Comment: The module() function expects an array of module names as second argument. Is uiCropper the name of a module that app depends on? If not, that won't work. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

Answer (score 0):

The string values you pass into a `module`'s dependencies array reference module names and must equal the string passed as the first argument of `angular.module()`.

For example...

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
 'uiCropper'
]);
```

...creates an AngularJS module named "app" that depends on another module named "uiCropper":

```
var uiCropper = angular.module('uiCropper', []);
```